Special Usage for String.find() Function in Python
I have MNEA 0183 messages like:
MNEAMessages = [
    "$GPGGA, 3555.1581, E, 1248.5819, W, 768.1, M",
    "$GLGGA, 3555.1581, E, 1248.5819, W, 768.1, M",
    "$GAGGA, 3555.1581, E, 1248.5819, W, 768.1, M",
    "$BDGGA, 3555.1581, E, 1248.5819, W, 768.1, M",
    "$GLRMC, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6",
    "$GARMC, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6"
]

As you can see, I have messages starting with $GPGGA, $GARMC. My goal is to find and count the messages containing $xxGGA. I have written the following code to do this.
counterGGA = 0
for message in MNEAMessages:
    startIndex = message.find("$")
    if startIndex != -1 and (message[startIndex + 3 : startIndex + 6] == "GGA"):
        # Oh yeah, it is a GGA message
        counterGGA += 1

print(counterGGA) # This gives me the number 4 as I want.

I'm wondering if there's a shorter or more efficient way to do this. For example, like this:
if message.find("$xxGGA"):
    # Hell yeah, it is better way to find GGA messages.
    counterGGA += 1

SOLUTION
Thank you for suggesting regex to me. I found exactly what I was looking for.
import re

match = re.search("\\$..GGA", message)
if match != None:
   counterGGA += 1 # Also match.start() gives start index like find() method


String methods only handle exact matches, so you cannot skip over characters like that.  The re (regular expression) module can do this - the pattern r"\$..GGA" would match your string (note that $ needs to be escaped since it has special meaning in a pattern, and the string literal has to be made raw so that it can contain that backslash).

if message[0] == '$' and message[3:6] == 'GGA'

You could use re.match to look for strings containing that pattern, the loop over your list in a generator expression
>>> import re
>>> sum(1 if re.match('\$[\w]{2}GGA', s) else 0 for s in MNEAMessages)
4

